# What is the appropriate term for a brochure with maps and shop information of the shopping mall?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, expressions

I'm wondering what the appropriate term is for a brochure that you can find at a shopping mall or department store — like 10 pages — that shows you the floor map + brief information on the shops.

1. Floor map
2. Floor guide
3. Any other suggestions?

In this situation, "guide" is not appropriate? It seems like "guide" should be used when the information/explanation is more detailed. I want to know its general term.

Another question is that when some restaurants are included in this brochure and you want to emphasize it, which of followings sounds more natural?

1. Floor and restaurant map/guide
2. Floor and gourmet map/guide
3. No need to indicate the presence of restaurants.  For this kind of stuff, just "floor map/guide" is fine.

My colleague who edits this brochure asked me (he wants to use this on the front page, as the title), and the more I search, the more I become confused.  Please help me to pick the most generally used expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Floor" goes with "map", not so much "guide". The most personable way to present it might be as "*Your* guide" to shops and restaurants in the mall rather than "floor - anything". Similar guides often have coupons with small savings on the meals at the participating restaurants to encourage commerce there.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and also editing my question.  Both are a big help for me.  The term "floor guide" is used in Japanese as it is, so we tend to assume it is also acceptable in English.  I visited a lot of websites of American shopping malls, but could not find any using "floor - anything" pattern.  Most of them are just "map" or even without any caption. I like your suggestion, "Your guide".  It sounds gentle and familiar.

Comment: My thanks to you and the one, not I, who graciously edited your question. Everyone works to be helpful here. As for accuracy, I have found that accuracy and idiom are usually shopping at opposite ends of the mall.